# Java Swing GUI Not Displaying in Xmonad

Tags: java, swing, haskell, xmonad

I have a Java swing GUI that runs and displays fine using other window managers but when I run it in Xmonad it does not display correctly. All that displays is the frame of the window which is grayed out with no buttons, menus, etc. How can I make the Swing GUI display correctly?

Answer (score 11):

In `~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs` add  `import XMonad.Hooks.SetWMName`.

Then add `startupHook = setWMName "LG3D"` to tell Xmonad to use `LG3D` as the window manager name.

```
xmonad $ defaultConfig
  { ...
    startupHook = setWMName "LG3D",
  }
```

Lastly, restart Xmonad using mod-q to reload xmonad.hs.

Sources:

http://thinkingeek.com/2012/01/24/fix-java-gui-applications-xmonad/

http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-SetWMName.html

Comment: the import should be `Monad.Hooks.SetWMName`. I wonder why StackOverflow doesn't allow edits that change only one character.

Comment: This works for Android Studio (3.6.x at the moment) on a fresh Ubuntu where you install XMonad and launch Android Studio.

Answer (score 3):

For a 100% explicit answer, just paste this into `~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs`:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.SetWMName

main = xmonad defaultConfig
    { startupHook = setWMName "LG3D" }
```

Comment: Works great!   What a relief!